# Specifying command to run with argsparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am writing a python program which has different behavior, i.e. it calls different function, for different [command] argument. These commands can be chosen from a list of specified commands. Currently I have:

```
parser.add_argument("command", choices=["command1", "command2"])
```

However this means I can't specify help message for each different commands and it seems a bit hacky. Is there a correct way of doing this, which would allow me to specify help for each command?

EDIT: How can I insure that the command is the first argument?

Comment: Make each command its own argument?

Comment: Would that have to be a flag?

Answer (score 2):

In order for each command to have its own help message, `command` needs to be a [subcommand](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) rather than a positional argument:

```
command = parser.add_subparsers(title='command', dest='command')
command.add_parser('command1', help='Foo all your bars')
command.add_parser('command2', help='Bar all your foos')
```

Comment: Then if someone passes 'command1' then `args.command=command1`?

Comment: When I use this method I get the command format from help:  program.py [<my flags>] {command1,command2} ... [other_arg], however when I'm trying to run `program.py command1 arg` it says error: unrecognized arguments: arg

Comment: also the "command" is not listed as a positional argument but instead at the end as "command"

Comment: @Ela: Yes to your first comment.  Each subparser needs to have its own set of positional arguments added separately; see the documentation for examples.